# Do I need to overload delete if I have operator T *()?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

If I have a template class `A` which holds a pointer, and `A` has an implicit conversion operator which will return that pointer, do I need to, or should I, define a `delete` operator for `A`, if I intent to apply `delete` to objects of this class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you've got something like the following:

```
template <typename T>
struct A {
  T * t;
  operator T* () { return t; } 
};
```

An you intend to "apply `delete` to objects of this class", so by that I'm assuming you mean:

```
void foo ()
{
  A<int> * p = new A<int>;
  delete p;     // Applying 'delete'
}
```

If this is the case, then the call to delete correctly destroys the object and frees the the memory allocated by the use of 'new' on the previous line and the answer to your question is 'no'.

Because you have declared a conversion operator to a pointer, it is possible to use `delete` on an object of type `A<int>` (a opposed to `A<int>*`).  The use of `delete` will be applied to the result of calling the conversion operator:

```
void foo ()
{
  A<int> a;
  a.t = new int;
  delete a;       // Same as: delete a.operator T*()
}
```

---

*Basics of how delete works:*

The expression `delete p`, does two different things.  Firstly, it calls the destructor for the object pointed to by `p` and then it frees the memory.  If you define an `operator delete` member for your class then it will be that function which will be used by `delete p` to free the memory.

In general, you only define those operators when you want to control how the memory for dynamic objects of that class should be allocated or freed.

Comment: Thanks Richard. Yes, it's usage like your last example I'm faced with. I was worried there may, in principle, be ambiguous situations: say if there were more than one conversion operator returning pointers.

Comment: If you have more than one conversion operator to a pointer type, then using 'delete' on the object will be a compile error.  FDIS of C++ '11 says:  "The operand shall have a pointer to object type, or a class type having a single non-explicit conversion function (12.3.2) to a pointer to object type."

Answer (score 5):

You only need to define *operator delete* if you define *operator new* -- in which case you pretty much must do so.

That doesn't mean that something won't need to delete your A*s -- but you don't need to define any operators for that, it will work by default.

Answer (score 2):

If your class *owns* this pointer, it should delete it in its destructor. Be aware that overloading this operator may be confusing, because the usual approach to obtain a pointer to an object is by taking its address.

Comment: Delete it in its "destructor", yes?

Comment: On your second point, are you thinking of 'operator &'?  Overloading "operator T*" should not affect taking the address of the object?

Comment: @Richard: Indeed, it should not. I was trying to point out that overloading that there may be scenarios when overloading that operator is not actually what the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

Does you class `A` *really* need to define an implicit conversion operator? Maybe have a simple `T* get() const` method that returns the pointer, like the boost and std smart pointer do. Implicit conversion can cause all kinds of trouble.